# Storcli - migrate from RAID1 to RAID10

Tags: migration, raid1, raid10, storcli

I have a system with two hard drives set up in RAID1. I've purchased another two - same model/size etc. - and now I want to reconfigure them to RAID10.

I have storcli installed in VMWare and is working, but I can't find anything about converting to raid10, just raid5/6...

I've found only how to create raid10 from scratch:
`storcli -CfgSpanAdd -r10 -Array0[64:0,64:1] -Array1[64:2,64:3] -a0`

But nothing on how to migrate existing array of two disks to four.

Of course, I would like to preserve existing data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Berfore trying anything, do a real and validated backup on another disk !

Comment: Of course, thank you, that goes without saying!